# How can I remove SyntaxError using RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting one syntax error and unable to remove it while i am working on Rails environment.Please read the below error and check my code which is explained below.

## Error:

```
SyntaxError in Homes#managebooks

Showing C:/Site/library_management1/app/views/homes/managebooks.html.erb where line #106 raised:

C:/Site/library_management1/app/views/homes/managebooks.html.erb:106: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting tASSOC
...remove_path(:id => @books.id) :confirm => "Are you sure to r...
```

My codes are as follows.

## views/homes/managebooks.html.erb

```
<% if admin_signed_in? %>
<div class="bar">
  Logged in as <strong><%= current_admin.email %></strong>.
  <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> |
  <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_admin_session_path, method: :delete, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
</div>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Sign up", new_admin_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %> |
  <%= link_to "Login", new_admin_session_path, :class => 'navbar-link'  %>
<% end %>
<div class="big-container">
    <% if flash[:color]== "valid" %>
        <div class="valid_notice">
            <p><%= flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <% elsif flash[:color]== "invalid"%>
        <div class="invalid_notice">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%else%>
        <div class="notice">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%end%>
<div class="admin-image">
 <div class="bpaddingdiv1"><img src="/assets/admin.png" border="0" name="admin" /></div>
</div>
<div class="borderlightgreen"></div>
<div class="admin-name">
<div class="tpaddingdiv2 textaligncenterdiv"><img src="/assets/adminpanel.png" border="0" name="admin" /></div>
</div>
<div class="leftside">
<div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
<li><a href="/homes/managebooks">Manage Books</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Manage Pages</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Manage Header Banner</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Brand</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="middlebox">
<center>
    <%= form_for :books,:url => {:action => "savebooks"} do |f| %>
    <fieldset>
         <p>
            <label for="name">Book name</label>
            <%= f.text_field :book_name,placeholder:"enter book name" %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="tel">Book title</label>
            <%= f.text_field :book_title,placeholder:"enter book title" %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="email">Author Name</label>
           <%= f.text_field :author_name,placeholder:"enter book author name" %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <label for="password">publisher Name</label>
            <%= f.text_field :publisher_name,placeholder:"enter book publisher name" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password"> Edition</label>
           <%= f.text_field :edition,placeholder:"enter book edition" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password">Pages</label>
           <%= f.text_field :pages,placeholder:"enter book pages" %>
         </p>
         <p>
            <label for="password"> Date of pursase</label>
            <%= f.date_select :date_of_purchase %>
         </p>

         <p>
            <%= f.submit "SUBMIT" %>
         </p>
    </fieldset>
 <% end %>
</center>
<% if params[:id] %>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Book name</th>
<th>Book title</th>
<th>Author Name</th>
<th>publisher Name </th>
<th>Edition</th>
<th>Pages</th>
<th>Date of pursase</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%= @books.book_name %></td>
    <td><%= @books.book_title %></td>
    <td><%= @books.author_name %></td>
    <td><%= @books.publisher_name %></td>
    <td><%= @books.edition %></td>
    <td><%= @books.pages %></td>
    <td><%= @books.date_of_purchase  %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag("/assets/1.png") %></td>
    <td><%= link_to image_tag("/assets/logout.png", :alt => "image", :width => 40, :height => 40, :title => "Delete item"),:method => :delete ,homes_remove_path(:id => @books.id) ,:confirm => "Are you sure to remove this?" %></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<% end  %>
</div>
</div>
```

Please try to help me for removing this syntax error.I am using rails version 3.2.19 and ruby version 1.9.3.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This line is not correct, the url needs to come in front of the options:

```
<%= link_to(
      image_tag(
        "/assets/logout.png", 
        :alt => "image", :width => 40, :height => 40, :title => "Delete item"
      ),
      homes_remove_path(:id => @books.id),
      :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure to remove this?") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that you need a comma before `:confirm` in this line:

```
`remove_path(:id => @books.id) :confirm => "Are you sure to r...`
```

It's hitting a `:` when it expects a comma or the end of the method call and that's what the error means.